# vb.net, webbrowser, many same classname

Tags: vb.net, classname

Yesterday I asked how to get the text in a div which has no ID.
People gave me this very good answer:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
        If d.GetAttribute("className") = "js-text-container" Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = d.InnerText
        End If
    Next
```

But now I'm facing a new problem: I realized that many articles have the same class name "js-text-container , and when I click the `button1`, in my richtextbox I get the text of the LAST div with this class name...

How to get the text in the FIRST div with the class named "js-text-container"?

Comment: just exit the loop after you found the first one... did you try doing a breakpoint and looking at what it is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exit the loop after you found the first element...

```
Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For Each d As HtmlElement In divs
    If d.GetAttribute("className") = "js-text-container" Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = d.InnerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You should learn how to use breakpoint and step the code. You would've notice this right away.

Comment: same answer after your advice, i feel like a pro :D

Comment: true, I ll learn this, it seems very usefull, thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Wow guys you answered me so fast, thanks a lot !!!!!
You guys were totaly right, i had just to exit the loop, but I didn t know the command "exit for"
Thanks guys, i learnt something !

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim divs = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div")

    For Each d As HtmlElement In divs

        If d.GetAttribute("className") = "js-text-container" Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = d.InnerText
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Best regards, this community is awesome !